# How can I evaluate an expression in a string?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to evaluate an expression in a string at run time . Not sure how to achieve this in Flex. My requirement is as follows

```
var test:String = "myparams.id=10" ;
//test will be a string populated at runtime.
// I need to treat it as an expression and evaluate it at runtime

if(test)

{

 // do something

}

else

{
 //do something
}
```

is it possible to do something like this action script 3?

I believe the eval function earlier allowed this, but now it has been depreciated?

Regards
Aparna

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var nameValuePairs : Array = test.split('=');
var variableName : String = nameValuePairs[0];
var variableValue : String = nameValuePairs[1];
```

But it's better to avoid such parsing and use XML or JSON or something else if you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on doing this a lot, or if you plan on trying to parse more complicated mathematical expressions, then consider using a MathParser class:

http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/mathparser/mp1.html

Answer (score 0):

daniel is absolutely right, you should avoid using this, but if you have to, it will work like this:

```
private var myId : Number = 10;
public function StringTest()
{
    var myTestString : String = "myId=10";
    var array : Array = myTestString.split("=");
    if(this[array[0]] == array[1])
    {
        trace("variable " + array[0] + " equals " + array[1]);
    }
}
```

If you only compare array[0] to array[1] it will compare the strings, but using this[array[0]] will look for a variable with this identifier within the scope of your function. Beware that it will throw a ReferenceError if the variable is not found. So you might want to put this into a try{..}catch(error:ReferenceError){...} statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myparams.id=0;

// ...
// ...
// ...

var test:String = "myparams.id=10";<br>
setTimeout(test, 0);
```

Comment: -1 - Question is for ActionScript, not JavaScript.  Even though ActionScript does have it's own [flash.utils.setTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()), unlike the JS version it requires an argument of type Function, not a String.  Hence, you'd still have to parse the string to an expression, which begs the question.